# How do I calculate values across three columns for a given formula?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am using SQL Server 2000. I am trying to calculate Net Promoter Score or NPS based on the below formula

***Formula***: `(Promoters - Detractors) / Total Questions`

- Scores 9 - 10 are considered *promoters*.
- Scores 0 -  6 are considered *detractors*.
- Scores 7 -  8 are considered *neutral*.

I have the following data:

```
Time           Q1      Q2      Q3
-----------  ------  ------  ------
2012-03-14      7       7       5
2012-03-15      3       2       5
2012-03-15      7      NA       2
2012-03-15      9      10     NULL
2012-03-15      8       4       4
2012-03-15     NA       6       4
2012-03-16      1       7       4
2012-03-16     NULL     0       5
2012-03-17      9       9       2
2012-03-19      0       0       1
2012-03-19      8       5       4
2012-03-19      1       0       3
```

The person who originally wrote the database stored `NULL` values as blanks or NA `enter code here`in a **NVARCHAR** format (only god knows why..) so the query I am playing with now uses a **ISNUMERIC** and im trying not to count blank or NA values.

My query, which doesnt work properly looks like:

```
 SELECT CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Q1]) != 1 THEN 0
             WHEN CAST([Q1] AS int) >= 9 THEN 1
             WHEN CAST([Q1] AS int) <= 6 THEN -1
             ELSE 0 END)
    + SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Q2]) != 1 THEN 0
             WHEN CAST([Q2] AS int) >= 9 THEN 1
             WHEN CAST([Q2] AS int) <= 6 THEN -1
             ELSE 0 END)
    + SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Q3]) != 1 THEN 0
             WHEN CAST([Q3] AS int) >= 9 THEN 1
             WHEN CAST([Q3] AS int) <= 6 THEN -1
             ELSE 0 END)
   AS FLOAT)
    / (SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Q1]) != 1 THEN 0
               ELSE 1 END)
    + SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Q2]) != 1 THEN 0
               ELSE 1 END)
    + SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Q3]) != 1 THEN 0
               ELSE 1 END)
   ) as [NPS]
FROM [nps]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, changing the data type of the column from `NVARCHAR` to `INT` would be ideal.

Here is the query that might help you get the result that you need.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle using SQL Server 2012**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90a91/1)

*Script*:

```
SELECT  
        (
            SUM (CASE WHEN q >= 9 THEN 1.  END) -
            SUM (CASE WHEN q <= 6 THEN 1.  END)
        ) /
        SUM (1.) AS nps
FROM
(
        SELECT  (CASE   
                    WHEN ISNUMERIC(q1) <> 1 THEN 0. 
                    ELSE CAST(q1 AS FLOAT) 
                END) AS q   
        FROM [nps] 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT  (CASE 
                    WHEN ISNUMERIC(q2) <> 1 THEN 0. 
                    ELSE CAST(q2 AS FLOAT) 
                END) AS q   
        FROM [nps] 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT  (CASE 
                    WHEN ISNUMERIC(q3) <> 1 THEN 0. 
                    ELSE CAST(q3 AS FLOAT) 
                END) AS q   
        FROM [nps] 
) nps;
```

*Output*:

```
np
---------
-0.611111
```

Comment: @Brad - In this answer, if a field has `'NA'` or `NULL`, it is counted as a `0`. Which means that it gets counted as a detractor. By the questions description... 36 field, 4 are `'NA'` or `NULL` and should be ignored => 4 promoters, 22 detractors, 6 neutral, 32 total => (4-22)/32 => -0.5625 and not -0.6111 as in this answer.  *[This can be fixed with `WHERE qn <> 'NA'` on the three sub-queries.  But the overall processing of `<> 'NA'` plus the `ISNUMERIC()` plus the `CAST()` seems to be more CPU processing than is necessary.]*

Answer (score 0):

How about fixing the database?  Is there a case when NA or blank is misrepresented if the value is actually 0?  If not, convert all the blanks and NA's to 0, change the column datatype to int and not allow null.  Then your life becomes much simpler.

Comment: The Database administrator will not allow me to change the database.. NA or blank values mean the question was not answered. So converting them to 0 values wont work. I wish life were simpler sometimes.

Comment: I feel your pain, been a BI developer in that situation many a time :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with CASTing your data types.  Either change the schema, or deal with them natively.

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN [Q1] IN (      '9', '10') THEN  1.0
         WHEN [Q1] IN ('7',  '8', 'NA') THEN  0.0
         WHEN [Q1] IS NULL              THEN  0.0
                                        ELSE -1.0 END
  + CASE WHEN [Q2] IN (      '9', '10') THEN  1.0
         WHEN [Q2] IN ('7',  '8', 'NA') THEN  0.0
         WHEN [Q2] IS NULL              THEN  0.0
                                        ELSE -1.0 END
  + CASE WHEN [Q3] IN (      '9', '10') THEN  1.0
         WHEN [Q3] IN ('7',  '8', 'NA') THEN  0.0
         WHEN [Q3] IS NULL              THEN  0.0
                                        ELSE -1.0 END
  )
  /
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN [Q1] <> 'NA' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END
  + CASE WHEN [Q2] <> 'NA' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END
  + CASE WHEN [Q3] <> 'NA' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END
  )                                                        AS [nps]
FROM
  [nps]
```

The divisor is nice an simple; if the [Qn] value is NULL it fails the test and returns 0.0 :)

You can also simplify it even further, without changing the schema, by always using `NULL` instead of `'NA'`.